# Check if element has a specific attribute using HtmlAgilityPack in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML.

I want to check if an element has a specific attribute.

I want to check whether an `<a>` tag has the `href` attribute.

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()

doc.Load(New StringReader(content))

Dim root As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode
Dim anchorTags As New List(Of String)

For Each link As HtmlNode In root.SelectNodes("//a")
    If link.HasAttributes("href") Then doSomething() 'this doesn't work because hasAttributes only checks whether an element has attributes or not
Next
```

Comment: i am using exactly the same code in my program, and am getting an error in the foreach line `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Smith: in stead of using my code use the fixed code of Slaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
If link.Attributes("href") IsNot Nothing Then
```

Comment: can you help me attend to the error am getting in the comment above?

Comment: You need to figure out what is `null`.

Comment: i posted the issue am having here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252438/getting-a-tags-and-attribute-with-htmlagilitypack-with-vb-net