# getting <a> tags and attribute with htmlagilitypack with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

i have this code

```
Dim htmldoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()
htmldoc.LoadHtml(strPageContent)
Dim root As HtmlNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode

For Each link As HtmlNode In root.SelectNodes("//a")
    If link.HasAttributes("href") Then doSomething() 'this doesn't work because hasAttributes only checks whether an element has attributes or not
Next
```

but am getting an error  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

the document contains at least one anchor-tag? how do i check if an attribute exits?

i tried this `if link.HasAttributes("title") then`  and get another error

`Public ReadOnly Property HasAttributes() As Boolean' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If HtmlAgilityPack supports this XPATH selector, you can replace `//a` with `//a[@href]`

```
For Each link as HtmlNode In root.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    doSomething()
Next
```

Otherwise, you can use the `Attributes` property:

```
For Each link as HtmlNode In root.SelectNodes("//a")
    If link.Attributes.Any(Function(a) a.Name = "href") Then doSomething()
Next
```

Comment: @jay am not extracting links only, but both the title attrib and the innerText, so how do i do this?

Comment: @Smith `HasAttributes` is not a method, it is a property -- you cannot use parentheses and arguments. There is also an `Attributes` property, which will return all of the attributes associated with a given element node. What line of code results in the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @Smith More to your question, see my second example. Within the `For…Each` block, you can inspect `link.Attributes` to see whether it contains an `href` attribute, but you can also check for other attributes and/or use the `link.InnerText` property to get the inner text of the anchor tag.

Comment: @jay thanks what if i want to check it there is a `title` or `alt` or other attributes, how do i perform this check?

Comment: @Smith Modify the example code: `If link.Attributes.Any(Function(a) a.Name = "alt") Then doSomething()`

Comment: @jay this code i guess it uses linq, will it work with .net 2.0

Comment: @Smith For .NET 2.0, you just need to do a `For Each` loop over `link.Attributes`, and inspect `.Name` for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim htmldoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()
htmldoc.LoadHtml(strPageContent)
Dim root As HtmlNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode

var nodes = root.SelectNodes("//a[@href and @title]")
if (nodes <> Null) Then
    For Each link As HtmlNode In nodes
        If link.HasAttributes("href") Then doSomething() 'this doesn't work because hasAttributes only checks whether an element has attributes or not
    Next
end if
```

Also, you can check for attributes:
link.Attributes["title"] if null, then doesnt have attribute.
Same link.Attributes["href"] and etc.

Property link.HasAttributes shows only that tag has any attribute, it is bool value.