# How to get a URL from the href attribute

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I can't get URLs from href attributes.
I use this code

```vb
Dim url As String = "http://example.com/"
Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

For Each item As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/@href")
    If Not item Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write(item.OuterHtml)
    End If
Next
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting <a> tags and attribute with htmlagilitypack with vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252438/getting-a-tags-and-attribute-with-htmlagilitypack-with-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `href` is an attribute you need to put it in square brackets `[]`

Remember attributes go in to square brackets when you are searching by them.

```
//a[@href]
```

In your case you need to get all `//a` nodes, then check for `HasAttributes("href")` and finally, get `Attributes("href")`.

```
For Each item As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")
    If Not item Is Nothing And item.HasAttributes("href") Then
        Response.Write(item.Attributes("href").Value)
    End If
Next
```